# runtimewarning courutine messagable.send was never awaited

Tags: python, discord.py, coroutine

A bit of background
I've been trying to make a discord bot as my first pet project after learning a bit of python .My aim is to retrieve API data from an online game I have been playing and paste it on my  discord server.The player ID of the data that I need to retrieve is given from the discord command.For ex: `!stats 2255880` is the command where 2255880 is the in-game player ID.I have almost completed the code,except the infernal error i keep getting and google did not help me much

The error:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited
  message.channel.send(end_data )
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

```
#to import modules
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import requests
import json


#client for bot
client=discord.Client()

######## TORN API DATA #########


apikey='insert key here'


@client.event
async def on_message(message):

   if message.content.startswith('!stats'):
      def torn_script(player_ID):
         apiurl='https://api.torn.com/user/'+str(player_ID)+'?selections=personalstats&key='+apikey
         r=requests.get(apiurl)
         astext=r.text
         asdict=json.loads(astext)
         data=json.loads(requests.get(apiurl).text)['personalstats']
         print('attacks won: ',data['attackswon'])
         async def discord_display(end_data):
            await message.channel.send(end_data )
         discord_display(['finally the dumbass succeded.LOL']) 
   torn_script(message.content[6:])
```

Comment: Did you try Ctrl-F'ing "send" in your code? Do you know what `await` is?

Comment: I did add it                `async def discord_display(end_data):
            await message.channel.send(end_data )
         discord_display(['finally the dumbass succeded.LOL']) `       but got the same message

Comment: In your `def discord_display` you must make it like this `await message.channel.send(end_data)`

Comment: @Abdulaziz I did change the code.I updated thecode above.But it is still giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Since `discord_display` is a coroutine (`async def discord_display()`), you need to await it:

```py
async def discord_display(end_data):
    await message.channel.send(end_data )
await discord_display(['finally the dumbass succeded.LOL'])
```

PS: Why are you still using `discord.Client` if you have imported `commands.Bot` ? The [`Commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=commands) extension way more practical and powerful.